# Problema com String multilinha para twitter API em Dart

Tags: json, string, dart, twitter-api

Estou criando um bot que posta tweets em Dart. Estou tendo problemas pois quero postar com quebra de linha mas não consigo, aparece o seguinte erro quando eu tento converter uma string em json atráves do pacote twitter_api:

[Quando eu atribuo a string ao 'status' dá esse erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjdOo.png)

aqui é parte do meu código:

```
void tweetBuild(Map twitterKeys) async {
  final String _tweetText = "In this part comes the tweet text, when I put \n, it doesn't works";

  final _twitterOauth = new twitterApi(
  consumerKey: twitterKeys['apiKey'],
  consumerSecret: twitterKeys['apiKeySecret'],
  token: twitterKeys['accessToken'],
  tokenSecret: twitterKeys['acessTokenSecret']
  );

  Future tweetRequest = _twitterOauth.getTwitterRequest(
    'POST',
    'statuses/update.json',
    options: {
        'status' :  _tweetText
    }
    );

    var response = await tweetRequest;
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);

 }
```

Comment: Tentou fazer a url-encode de sua mensagem com ```Uri.encodeFull(_tweetText);```? Lembre-se de importar a biblioteca respectiva(dart:core).

Comment: quando é postado, no twitter, ele não converte de volta, então vai todos os codigos

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei quanto a esse *package* aí pois nunca usei. Mas, como você tá criando a String direto em Dart, é necessário escapar o caractere `\`, então para cada `\` coloque mais um `\\`:

```dart
final String _tweetText = "In this part comes the tweet text, when I put \\n, it doesn't works";
```

Comment: Se eu faço isso, o erro continua, bem parecido, só muda os index